# iOS - is it possible to select view for a uitabbar at runtime?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am assigning my view controller to my tab right after I create it. Is it possible to select the view that will show after the tab is clicked?

For eg
    //user clicks tab 1
    if(hasMessages)
          //show view A
     else
          //show view B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to set a delegate for your tab controller:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBarController.delegate = self;  // or whatever suitable class you have
```

This delegate needs to conform to the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol.

In your delegate, implement `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` and inside it, find out which view you want to present. Assuming your tab's root view controller is a navigation controller, then the delegate method implementation would be something like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    /* logic goes here */

    [viewController pushViewController:someNewVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I meant, I want to select tab 1, but depending on some boolean I want to show viewA or viewB. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I realised that you meant something different so I just edited my answer!